# How to use JSP Expression Language to compute request data

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

```
<c:set var="zc_BtnFont_Style" value="${zc_BtnFont};" scope="request"/>
```

Here I have access to manipulate parameter *zc_BtnFont* since it is from *HttpServletRequest.getParameter()*. But I can't dynamically evaluate this expression.

I've seen older posts in SO, that explains about problems that cause this to happen.

Here,

1.My web.xml points to http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd

2.EL ignore is not done in page level or through web.xml.

I can hardcode an EL {1+1} to evaluate it to true, so I think it is not ignored here. But if i send from request 1+1 becomes 1 1 due to *+* being considered as space. I've tried URL encoding as 1%2B1, then it renders as "1+1" and not 2.

I understand the security risk of EL Injection and just want to know how to achieve this.

Comment: I can see a `;` with `value="${zc_BtnFont};"`. You should't put it in the JSTL expresssion.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It is not in the expression, so it is fine

Comment: @JasperdeVries : No this doesn't solve. I can access the param but not make it to evaluate.

Comment: @JasperdeVries: I guess OP's concrete problem is that the actual value of the `${zc_BtnFont}` variable represents a `String` which in turn represents yet another EL expression, e.g. `1+1` and the OP simply wanted to evaluate exactly that in the JSP's EL context. I.e. OP's real question is ultimately "How do I programmatically evaluate an EL expression in a String?"

Comment: @BalusC yeah.. think you are right.

Comment: Yes. Can you help me achieve this? I've sure seen EL injection cases like this earlier. @BalusC